# How to set xslt function return value to a variable?

Tags: xslt

I need to further process an xsl value that I generated like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(xs:dateTime('2006-02-15T17:00:00-03:00'), xs:dayTimeDuration('-PT7H'))" />
```

I want to take the result of that and keep only a few substrings (3 substrings operations).

How can I achieve that? For now the code above dumps the result in the resulting transformation as '2006-02-15T13:00:00-07:00'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a variable to the value your function returns and then use that variable for any other transformations.

```
<xsl:variable name="result" select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(xs:dateTime('2006-02-15T17:00:00-03:00'), xs:dayTimeDuration('-PT7H'))" />
```

or

```
<xsl:variable name="result">
    <xsl:value-of select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(xs:dateTime('2006-02-15T17:00:00-03:00'), xs:dayTimeDuration('-PT7H'))" />
</xsl:variable>
```

and then

```
<xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
```